# Round decimal to nearest even cent

Tags: c#

How do you round up to the nearest even cent?.
So, for the following decimals,
I want to round and display dollar amount:

```
1230.3092 => $1230.30
221.9672 => $221.96
12345.6808 => 12345.68
```

I've tried this

```
Math.Round(value, 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven)
decimal.Round(value, 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven)
```

but some reason it rounds up.

Comment: That's not how rounding works.  If you want to define your own custom rules of mathematics then you'll have to implement those rules yourself.  The built-in components use the standard rules of mathematics.

Comment: Add more examples, eg `1.005`, `10000000000.05`. This is not obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want this:

```
(0.02m / 1.00m) * decimal.Round(value * (1.00m / 0.02m))
```

`value * (1.00m / 0.02m)` is the amount of money in terms of a "2-cents" unit. Round in that space to an integer, and then convert back to dollars.

`MidpointRounding` should be used to determine how you want, for example, `100.01m` to round, since it is halfway between `100.00m` and `100.02m`.

Comment: So that is the default, why specify it?

Comment: this still rounds up to 1230.31, and it should be: 1230.30

Comment: @TimothyShields: The question is actually trickier than you think ;)

Comment: var total = 0.01m * decimal.Round(100 * 1230.3092m, MidpointRounding.ToEven); => total has ...31 :(

Comment: @leppie I misunderstood what MidpointRounding.ToEven was doing and have completely changed my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to follow nonstandard rules for rounding, so the built-in functions won't do what you are looking for.  Either overload the methods or create your own - it looks like you just need to truncate to two decimals, then add one if the result is odd (or floor then add one).

Comment: Halfway means halfway:  1230.3050 is halfway.  1230.3092 is not.